# find rotated side closet distance

Tags: android, math, mathematical-optimization

I have two square views outerSquare and innerSquare , outer squre x and y position  from top left is x1 and y1,inner square x and y position from top left is x2 and y2, i can find the closet distance between left outerside and left innerside using (x2-x1) but when we rotate outerside  at angel of A in radian we got cross side now we can not use over simple formula because of cross line so help me to find closest distance distance between inner square and outersquare after rotation

[not rotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVpzp.png)

[rotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzDde.png)

i want find closet distance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi. Would this help? [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248617/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

Comment: a) The horizontal yellow line in the second picture is **not** the shortest distance you are talking about in the text. The shortest distance would be the perpendicular line on the square side of the large square.  Do you want to calculate the length of the yellow line or the shortest distance? b) Do you rotate the outer square around its **center**? c) To solve the problem, you need to know the side length of the larger square. You know that, don't you?